# How to use webpack's async import with angular CLI?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to use webpack's (2.2.1) async module loading as described [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/).  I've taken a look at some of the [examples](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/harmony) as well.

The problem is that no matter how I do it, I get the error `Declaration or statement expected`.

It really doesn't matter where I put it, clearly `import` as a function just isn't known to my environment (Angular 4.0.3, Angular CLI 1.0.1, TypeScript 2.2.2).

...but just for the sake of providing an example, here's one:

```
import('./myModule').then( (myModule) => {

//doesn't matter what is in here
//Nor does it matter what module I try to import or how I refer to it - same error no matter what.
});
```

It doesn't matter where this code is.  I want it in my `ngOnInit` method, but I've tried it just up with the rest of my imports as it appears in the example linked to.

How do I use this feature?  Do I have to import something (yes, I see the irony in asking how to import my ability to import)? None of the examples show having to do anything other than just use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support is included in TypeScript 2.4 which is currently in release candidate.

So run

```
npm i --save-dev typescript@rc
```

or

```
jspm i typescript@rc
```

and go to town.

You can track the progress of this item on GitHub in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14495 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/14774

Comment: Btw, RC was just released: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/12/announcing-typescript-2-4-rc/